# NPM unable to find package.json - VueJS on Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to up a `vue js` app with `docker-compose`, but when docker trying 'npm install', the logs shows that npm cannot find a file package.json. Notice that i created a `vue js` project with `vue js cli` before i trying to up app with docker-compose* I verified if the directory is wrong, but i cannot see anything wrong . I'm running `docker` commands on vue project root. The `docker-compose` file is inside another project
My `Dockefile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir /globostore-frontend
WORKDIR /globostore-frontend

ENV PATH /globostore-frontend/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /globostore-frontend

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
     - '3306:3306'
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'Globostore'
      MYSQL_USER: 'wendel'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'wendel12'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'wendel12'
    volumes: 
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
  web:
    build: .
    command: flask run
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - db
    links: 
      - db
    environment: 
      FLASK_ENV: development
  bff:
    build: ./../globostore-bff/
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
    environment: 
      FLASK_ENV: development
    command: flask run
  frontend:
    build: ./../globostore-frontend/
    volumes: 
      - .:/globostore-frontend
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
```

Error:

```
frontend_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
frontend_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
frontend_1  | npm ERR! path /globostore-frontend/package.json
frontend_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
frontend_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/globostore-frontend/package.json'
frontend_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
frontend_1  | npm ERR! enoent 
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
frontend_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T17_00_23_137Z-debug.log
```

This is my project directory structure

[image]

I start the application through the docker-compose file at `globostore-api` directory

Comment: Add your directory project structure and how/where you launch the `docker build`

Comment: @Max i added the project structure. check it out

Comment: I can't see the `package.json` on `globostore-api` directory. On Dockerfile you have `COPY package.json /globostore-frontend`

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

It looks like your error does not come from `docker build`. It looks like it comes from from this command: `npm run serve` executed during container start.

During docker build your npm install will work, because the `package.json` exists - **You copy it.**

But when you run `docker-compose up` this file does not exists because you override entire directory with `volumes` for frontend.

You have `docker-compose.yaml` next to those files:

- `.gitignore`
- `app.py`
- `Dockerfile`
- `Readme.md`
- `requirements.txt`

There is no `package.json` file, in that directory, you mount inside the `docker-compose.yaml`

In docker-compose you have this section:

```
 frontend:
    build: ./../globostore-frontend/
    volumes: 
      - .:/globostore-frontend
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
```

So you are overwriting volume here: `- .:/globostore-frontend`, you copied in docker build.

#### Solution

1. Remove this line
2. Replace `.:/globostore-frontend` to `./globostore-frontend:/globostore-frontend`

#### Do debugging yourself

You can do debugging yourself. Please find tutorial and follow my instructions:

1. Add command to docker-compose.yaml for the frontend service

You need to add this line: `command: ["sleep", "10000"]`

So your definition will look like:

```
 frontend:
    build: ./../globostore-frontend/
    volumes: 
      - .:/globostore-frontend
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    command: ["sleep", "1000"]
```

Then try to run docker-compose up and see if your container is working.

2. Find docker container ID

Run `docker ps` and find container id - this is container hash.

3. Shell into container

Run `docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID sh`. Now you are in the container and you can see if the `package.json` exists in the `/globostore-frontend` directory.

But the `package.json` will be missing because you override the `/globostore-frontend` dir with `volume` for a `frontend` in this lines:

```
volumes: 
   - .:/globostore-frontend
```

Comment: sorry, but i didnt understand so well your explanation. Is it wrong i ask 'npm install' on Dockerfile at globostore-frontend? the package.json file is at globostore-frontend, and i said on dockerfile: 'copy this package.json here into this directory 'globostore-frontend that i just created and run npm install ', and in docker-compose file, i mapped the directory where the dockerfile is into the globostore-frontend directory at the container, or am i wrong?

Comment: I have added more explaination, try to follow my debugging instruction, please